# Create lunch menu HTML with menu as bg image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website that resembles a restaurant menu that gets updated by our chef at my facility weekly. Basically I have an image I want to use and I want the text to write over top of the image.

I've tried a couple CSS codes and I cannot get anything to center up right with the image like I want. Any help would be appreciated. I want the image to be a little bigger than this - probably 800x600 (that way the text is nice and large as well)

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've done so far

Comment: this could be achieved a million and one ways. this isn't a site to discuss the best way to do something. you need to post code that you've done and what is specifically not working about it.

Comment: Read about floats and margins, absolute positioning, text-align.  If it's responsive then you'll have to do a bit more.

Comment: Here's what I have so far - just something simple to get me started `<html>
<head>
<title>GCH Cafe Menu</title>

<style type="text/css">

h1::before, h1::after {
    content: ""; display: block; height: 3em;
    background: url('bg.jpg') center center;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>

<h1>TEST</h1>




</body>
</html>
` Sorry I couldn't figure out how to make this spread out more..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would do it like this, clean and easy approach:

```css
.menu {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H3g5.jpg);
  width: 770px;
  height: 562px;
  padding: 25px 430px 25px 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h2>Menu position 1</h2>
  <p>menu 1.1</p>
  <p>menu 1.2</p>
  <p>menu 1.3</p>
  <h2>Menu position 2</h2>
  <p>menu 2.1</p>
  <p>menu 2.2</p>
  <p>menu 2.3</p>
</div>
```

The div has to be the same size as the image, and the paddings define basically the area where no text should be seen, so the 430px sets the area to the right of the text where it should not flow into.

for responsive layouts you can define media queries which use a smaller image and set the width, height and padding settings accordingly. Unfortunately i don't have an easy read for media queries, but you could use this for a start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: For some odd reason the image will not come through when I use that code - I changed it to my image by the way haha.

Comment: Couldn't you also set the div to relative in which case all you would have to do is set the height & width properties which is less trial and error in determining the values than all 4 padding values?

Comment: Got the image working - is there a way to center the image? I tried `background-position: center;` but it isn't working.

Comment: yes, this will not work, since the background image is only shown behind the div, so you need to position the div, which you can do with: margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Oh awesome! I think I'm good to go now. Thank you so much @TimeWaster for your help. I appreciate it very much!